# Android : crash because java class not found

Tags: android, loading, dex

My goal is to be able to make my Android TV Mi Box S (Oreo 8.1) transcode properly Dolby Digital+ (EAC3) sounds to Dolby Digital (AC3) and output it to, my AVR through SPDIF.

This transcodindg is possible with Kodi 18.1 applicition but is not proposed by other application or Android 8.1 settings. As Kodi is able to do it I reverse engineered Android stack. My conclusion are : - Android Oreo embeds any necessary codecs ans other stuff to do this transcoding but does not propose the settings to configure this - Android Pie proposes the wanted surround sound setting (output Dolby Digital on SPDIF)

So my goal is to backport Android TvSettings application from Pie to Oreo

I first tryed to generate TvSettings with Android Studio. I hacked the application resources but stopped when I understood that I would have to generate platfom dependacies (for instance SettingsLib.jar)

My second trial is to generate the entire Android platform. The build is complete and I can deploy TvSettings application on a x86 TV simulation BUT when I launched the TvSettings appplication I get this error :

--------- beginning of crash

> 2019-04-01 12:21:04.976 3987-3987/com.android.tv.settings
>   E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>       Process: com.android.tv.settings, PID: 3987
>       java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to get provider android.support.v4.content.FileProvider:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class
>   "android.support.v4.content.FileProvider" on path: DexPathList[[zip
>   file
>   "/data/app/com.android.tv.settings-2DkaCncwGQ874WP-kx3G4Q==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.android.tv.settings-2DkaCncwGQ874WP-kx3G4Q==/lib/x86,
>   /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]

I searched this error on internet and it seems that it deals with multidex feature. This multidex feature is well documented for clean developped Android appliacation but nor reaally for applications extracted from Android platform and deployed with adb.

This problem is related to java libraries loading. 
I found threads referring Android multidex feature but only for applications buils with Android Studio/Gradle and my app was build with Android platform

What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

have you included fileProvider in your manifest?

Comment: Well, I did not yet change TvSettings AndroidManifest.xml that already contains :              <provider android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
                  android:authorities="com.android.settings.files"
....

Answer (score 0):

Well there seems to be a root error during deployment of my TvSettings application. Here is its log :

E/dex2oat: Invalid version number in dex file header.  File: base.apk

I read several pages and found this one very interesting : https://source.android.com/devices/tech/dalvik/configure

So, due to different optimizations, platform apps are not generated with the same file format that apps generated above platform API

My idea is to generate the whole platform including TvSettings app and to deploy TvSettings with adb. So the apk format may be wrong.

My next step is to add in TvSettings/Settings/Android.mk the flag below :

LOCAL_DEX_PREOPT := false